# X670 Elite AX WiFi/BT (RZ616) is not available on 22.04

Tags: boot, networking, drivers, wireless, kernel

### Problem

Can't get my RZ616 (MT7922A22M) WiFi + BT controller onboard my X670 Elite AX to appear in Ubuntu.

#### `nmcli d`

```
enp14s0          ethernet  connected               ASUS 10G NIC    
br-487453fc8154  bridge    connected (externally)  br-487453fc8154 
br-65946a0e6f0b  bridge    connected (externally)  br-65946a0e6f0b 
br-b483ca36a405  bridge    connected (externally)  br-b483ca36a405 
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)  docker0         
enp16s0          ethernet  unavailable             --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged               --
```

- **enp14s0** is a 10G NIC installed into a PCIE slot.
- **enp16s0** is the Realtek 2.5GbE LAN on the X670 Elite AX
- WiFi controller is not listed.

#### `lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Aquantia Corp.
       vendor: Aquantia Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:0e:00.0
       logical name: enp14s0
       version: 03
       serial: 58:11:22:52:f1:ca
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 10Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp 10bt-fd 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd 10000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=atlantic driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic duplex=full firmware=1.3.18 ip=10.4.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:fb800000-fb87ffff memory:fb8a0000-fb8a0fff memory:fb400000-fb7fffff memory:fb880000-fb89ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:10:00.0
       logical name: enp16s0
       version: 05
       serial: 74:56:3c:47:46:7d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.19.0-46-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:40 ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fbf00000-fbf0ffff memory:fbf10000-fbf13fff
  *-network
       description: Network controller
       product: MEDIATEK Corp.
       vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:11:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=mt7921e latency=0
       resources: irq:171 memory:fbc00000-fbcfffff memory:fbd00000-fbd07fff
```

Last item is the WiFi device.

#### `lspci -k -vv` (for WiFi device):

```
11:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
    Subsystem: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 0616
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 171
    Region 0: Memory at fbc00000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
    Region 2: Memory at fbd00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [80] Express (v2) Endpoint, MSI 00
        DevCap: MaxPayload 128 bytes, PhantFunc 0, Latency L0s unlimited, L1 unlimited
            ExtTag+ AttnBtn- AttnInd- PwrInd- RBE+ FLReset+ SlotPowerLimit 26.000W
        DevCtl: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq-
            RlxdOrd+ ExtTag+ PhantFunc- AuxPwr- NoSnoop+ FLReset-
            MaxPayload 128 bytes, MaxReadReq 512 bytes
        DevSta: CorrErr- NonFatalErr- FatalErr- UnsupReq- AuxPwr- TransPend-
        LnkCap: Port #1, Speed 5GT/s, Width x1, ASPM L0s L1, Exit Latency L0s <2us, L1 <8us
            ClockPM- Surprise- LLActRep- BwNot- ASPMOptComp+
        LnkCtl: ASPM Disabled; RCB 64 bytes, Disabled- CommClk+
            ExtSynch- ClockPM- AutWidDis- BWInt- AutBWInt-
        LnkSta: Speed 5GT/s (ok), Width x1 (ok)
            TrErr- Train- SlotClk+ DLActive- BWMgmt- ABWMgmt-
        DevCap2: Completion Timeout: Range ABCD, TimeoutDis+ NROPrPrP- LTR+
             10BitTagComp- 10BitTagReq- OBFF Not Supported, ExtFmt+ EETLPPrefix-
             EmergencyPowerReduction Not Supported, EmergencyPowerReductionInit-
             FRS- TPHComp- ExtTPHComp-
             AtomicOpsCap: 32bit- 64bit- 128bitCAS-
        DevCtl2: Completion Timeout: 50us to 50ms, TimeoutDis- LTR+ OBFF Disabled,
             AtomicOpsCtl: ReqEn-
        LnkCap2: Supported Link Speeds: 2.5-5GT/s, Crosslink- Retimer- 2Retimers- DRS-
        LnkCtl2: Target Link Speed: 5GT/s, EnterCompliance- SpeedDis-
             Transmit Margin: Normal Operating Range, EnterModifiedCompliance- ComplianceSOS-
             Compliance De-emphasis: -6dB
        LnkSta2: Current De-emphasis Level: -6dB, EqualizationComplete- EqualizationPhase1-
             EqualizationPhase2- EqualizationPhase3- LinkEqualizationRequest-
             Retimer- 2Retimers- CrosslinkRes: unsupported
    Capabilities: [e0] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/32 Maskable+ 64bit+
        Address: 00000000fee03000  Data: 0025
        Masking: fffffffe  Pending: 00000000
    Capabilities: [f8] Power Management version 3
        Flags: PMEClk- DSI- D1- D2- AuxCurrent=0mA PME(D0+,D1-,D2-,D3hot+,D3cold+)
        Status: D0 NoSoftRst+ PME-Enable- DSel=0 DScale=0 PME-
    Capabilities: [100 v1] Vendor Specific Information: ID=1556 Rev=1 Len=008 <?>
    Capabilities: [108 v1] Latency Tolerance Reporting
        Max snoop latency: 0ns
        Max no snoop latency: 0ns
    Capabilities: [110 v1] L1 PM Substates
        L1SubCap: PCI-PM_L1.2+ PCI-PM_L1.1+ ASPM_L1.2+ ASPM_L1.1+ L1_PM_Substates+
              PortCommonModeRestoreTime=3us PortTPowerOnTime=52us
        L1SubCtl1: PCI-PM_L1.2- PCI-PM_L1.1- ASPM_L1.2- ASPM_L1.1-
               T_CommonMode=0us LTR1.2_Threshold=262144ns
        L1SubCtl2: T_PwrOn=150us
    Capabilities: [200 v2] Advanced Error Reporting
        UESta:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UEMsk:  DLP- SDES- TLP- FCP- CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF- MalfTLP- ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        UESvrt: DLP+ SDES+ TLP- FCP+ CmpltTO- CmpltAbrt- UnxCmplt- RxOF+ MalfTLP+ ECRC- UnsupReq- ACSViol-
        CESta:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr-
        CEMsk:  RxErr- BadTLP- BadDLLP- Rollover- Timeout- AdvNonFatalErr+
        AERCap: First Error Pointer: 00, ECRCGenCap- ECRCGenEn- ECRCChkCap- ECRCChkEn-
            MultHdrRecCap- MultHdrRecEn- TLPPfxPres- HdrLogCap-
        HeaderLog: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
    Kernel driver in use: mt7921e
    Kernel modules: mt7921e
```

### Other info

- Ubuntu 22.04 running `5.19.0-46-generic` from `linux-generic-hwe-22.04` version `5.19.0.46.47~22.04.21`
- From my research I think the RZ616 is supported by `mt7922` (although `lspci` is showing use of `mt7921e`?)
- `/lib/firmware/mediatek` contains relevant patches: `BT_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1_1_hdr.bin`, `WIFI_MT7922_patch_mcu_1_1_hdr.bin`, `WIFI_RAM_CODE_MT7922_1.bin`

### Background

Setup a new system with an AORUS X670 Elite AX a week ago, installed 22.04 LTS. WiFi appeared to be working fine for a while (maybe a bit slow). Shutdown overnight, next morning, system failed to boot. Maybe a kernel update was installed?

Managed to recover from Live USB, boot into Ubuntu. During the process I was trying a lot of different things...

- ...installing newest mainline Linux kernel 6.4, which failed `update-initramfs` install because amdgpu-dkms failed to build. I eventually purged this kernel because aforementioned failure prevented my system from booting: removing it allowed a successful `update-initramfs`.
- ...reinstalling `amdgpu` drivers while trying to get the 6.4 kernel working. Evidently they don't build/install with the 6.x kernels though.

Finally managed to get booted back into Ubuntu (with now a much slower boot, USB errors, etc), but WiFI is dead. I suspect something about boot configuration/modules/drivers/updated kernel is to blame, but not entirely sure.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, this seems a bit absurd, but the solution here was to shutdown, disconnect my computer from power for a few minutes, reconnect the power cable, then reboot.

Amazingly, a lot of problems I was having (missing WiFi, slow boot, USB errors etc) all seem resolved (maybe related.)

**Best explanation I can offer...**

I was looking at what seemed to be an unrelated set of USB errors (`USB 2/3 device descriptor read64, error -110`) appearing during a very slow boot process and came across these threads:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13653692/device-descriptor-read-64-error-110
- https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1610142

On the last link:

> Something caught my eye after looking at some of the other threads. In one of them it mentioned something about power. I disconnected the machine, not shutdown -P and reconnected the power cord.

> Not only was I able to format with LVM as I was with the 9100 but after the reinstall there are no errant messages about the usb ports but the keyboard works perfectly.

So following this advice works. Afterwards, things look good in `nmcli d`:

```
wlp17s0          wifi      connected               Home         
br-487453fc8154  bridge    connected (externally)  br-487453fc8154 
br-65946a0e6f0b  bridge    connected (externally)  br-65946a0e6f0b 
br-b483ca36a405  bridge    connected (externally)  br-b483ca36a405 
docker0          bridge    connected (externally)  docker0         
enp16s0          ethernet  disconnected            --              
enp14s0          ethernet  unavailable             --              
lo               loopback  unmanaged               --
```

The resolution suggests it's a power management issue. Perhaps it was putting the WiFi device into an unstable, unusable state? Makes me a little concerned for the motherboard. But at least I have an interim fix.