# Unable to boot into Live-USB and always restart (22.04/23.10, Lenovo Legion R9000P 2023)

Tags: boot, dual-boot, live-usb

Currently I have series problem when preparing dual-boot Ubuntu 22.04.3 Desktop (Linux Kernel 6.2, [link of ISO](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.3/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso)), Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server ([link of ISO](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.3/ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso)) and Ubuntu 22.04.1 (Linux Kernel 5.15, [link of ISO](https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso)). LiveCD just failed to boot (seems to be stopped and rebooted when loading services, and thus X11 window is not loaded).

[Figure on booting Ubuntu 22.04.3 LiveCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsT2k.jpg)

↑ Laptop will stay at this stage for about 10 sec, then reboot ↑

Last Outputs found in Ubuntu 22.04.1 LiveCD (for the first time booting into LiveCD; for the second time, `(x of 5)` may not show on screen):

```
Started CUPS Schedular.
Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Serivce.
Finished Detect the available GPUs and deal with any system changes.
(1 of 5) A start job is running for Ubuntu live CD installer (19s / no limit)
(2 of 5) A start job is running for Network Manager Walt Online (21s / no limit)
(3 of 5) A start job is running for casper-md5check Verify Live ISO checksums (28s / no limit)
(4 of 5) A start job is running for Dispacher daemon for systemd-networkd (30s / 1min 35s)
(5 of 5) A start job is running for Snap Daemon (32s / 1min 35s)
```

It soon reboots (about 34s, instead of running out 1min 35s).

Additional notes for Ubuntu 22.04.3 Server:

- Could boot to installation interface by 1) boot into rescue mode, i.e., add `1` to grub linux; 2) then exit rescue mode.
- **Stuck about 10 seconds in options for network, then automatically reboot.** So I guess something failed for network service (either NetworkManager or systemd-networkd).

Hardware and Software specifications:

- Lenovo Legion R9000P ARX8 (2023); AMD Ryzen 9 7945 HX (Zen 4).
- No secure boot, UEFI mode. USB prepared by rufus-4.3 (GPT, UEFI no CSM, ISO mode instead of DD mode) or UltraISO.
- Windows 11 pre-installed and work fine.
- Have installed Ubuntu 22.04 once before (but found boot problems afterwards). While attempting to reinstall Ubuntu, I found I could not even boot into LiveCD. Since I have formatted previous Ubuntu, now I can't boot into rescue mode (sad QAQ).
- Power management seems to be controled by softwares in Windows. Quiet and normal modes are utilized, while performance/extreme mode is not applied during booting LiveCD.

Attempts tried thus far:

- Tried out various BIOS option combinations for wireless availability, switchable/discrete GPU mode, memory/CPU/GPU overclocking, VT, AMD security, ..., still not working.
- BIOS of my computer does not have ACHI option. So (maybe) I can't change that currently. But since this laptop only accepts NVME SSDs, I guess it's already ACHI.
- Grub option combinations `acpi=off noapci noirq nomodeset` tried, so seems not (or not only) an ACPI problem.
- Tried out other distributions, such as [Ubuntu 23.10.1 (not the legacy one)](https://releases.ubuntu.com/22.04.3/ubuntu-22.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso), [Fedora 39](https://mirror.nyist.edu.cn/fedora/releases/39/Workstation/x86_64/iso/Fedora-Workstation-Live-x86_64-39-1.5.iso), [ArchLinux 2023.11.01](http://mirrors.aliyun.com/archlinux/iso/2023.11.01/archlinux-2023.11.01-x86_64.iso?spm=a2c6h.25603864.0.0.131c4f0dlhbRKv). They behave similarly (reboot when starting services around network). ISO SHA256SUMS checked for Ubuntu 22.04.1 and 22.04.3 Desktop.
- Also tried out different USB ports (USB-3.0, USB-2.0). I currently have only one USB stick, so I could not verify whether it's the problem of the USB stick.

Hope someone could point out the what's the problem! Many thanks!

Comment: You've told us Ubuntu 22.04.3, but not which ISO as ISOs are available using the GA (5.15) kernel stack, and HWE (6.2) using different installers. You mention Ubuntu 23.10 but again not which ISO (three installers though not the kernel choice). Please note this is Ubuntu support, if you want to ask about Linux (inc. Ubuntu, Fedora & Arch) you can use SE *Unix & Linux*, but being specific is always helpful   (22.04 ISOs for Ubuntu Desktop are available using 5.15, 5.19 & 6.2 kernels currently if you're asking about Ubuntu Desktop, but you didn't say Desktop or Server, though do mention X11?)

Comment: @guiverc Hi! I've specified url links of ISO files. I found that problems in SE *Unix & Linux* is more about Linux itself, but not very focus on installation and drivers of Linux distributions. So I think that this question is somehow proper to be asked in *Ask Ubuntu*.

Comment: You've also mentioned kernel 6+; have you tried a Ubuntu 22.04 LTS ISO using an older kernel?  eg. https://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/22.04/ubuntu-22.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso has the 5.15 kernel on it; 22.04.2 Dekstop ISO will have 5.19 which allow easy *live* booting with different kernels.. You can always install offline (*so install contains only what is on ISO itself*) and then change kernel stack to GA so 22.04 will remain on the GA kernel (not upgrade to current 6.2 HWE & soon 6.5), though Server ISOs default to using GA (5.15) anyway.  This site is Ubuntu only

Comment: @guiverc Thanks for pointing out possibility of kernel version! Tried 22.04.1 out but still. Additional outputs, sha256sums checks also updated by edit to original question.

Comment: You can check that the USB pendrive is good (that the memory cells really contain the content from the iso file) if you first *clone* from the iso file to the pendrive (dd-mode in Rufus) and then use [diff-image-drive](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1958073&p=14142910#post14142910) version 1.3. In order to be sure that the data are read from the USB drive, you should reboot before running `diff-image-drive`

Comment: "Could boot to installation interface by 1) boot into rescue mode, i.e., add 1 to grub linux; 2) then exit rescue mode." <-- is this still working with Ubuntu Server? You suspect the network. What network hardware is it (brand name and model)? Is there only wifi or also ethernet (wired network)?

Comment: Instead of an ISO file with a live system and an installer, you can put an 'already installed' system onto your USB drive. Ubuntu has compressed image files of Ubuntu Server, and these are very portable, so if of of them will also fail in your computer, you can boot it in another computer, and then blacklist the wifi driver(s) and check it that makes it boot all the way in your computer. Then you know what is the problem and a workaround might be to get a USB-connected wifi chip or RJ-45 port and communicate that way until Linux catches up with a driver for the wifi hardware (maybe next year).

Comment: At the Ubuntu Forums you find [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2474692) about the compressed image files of Ubuntu Server. I would recommend the version jammy (22.04.x LTS) unless you have very new hardware. For very new hardware try the [compressed image of Ubuntu Server mantic (23.10)](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-server/daily-preinstalled/20231006/). If you make this work, you can install a desktop environment later, for example `ubuntu-desktop` to get standard Ubuntu Desktop or `kubuntu-desktop`, `lubuntu-desktop` etc to get a community flavour of Ubuntu.

Comment: @sudodus Many thanks! Actually, I've found a temporary solution for this problem, so not all details you've mentioned were validated. The most relevant guidance proven to be useful, could be that you pointed out the possibility of wifi driver problem. Still, I'm very grateful for these detailed and specific advices!

Comment: I'm glad that you found a temporary solution :-) I agree with user68186, that you should report a new bug or support an existing bug according to their comment at your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm trying to answer my own question, since a temporary resolution found.

**Probably a compatibility problem of ethernet hardware/software (PCIe) for dual-boot systems of Linux and Windows.**

<del>This problem may link to another thread: [X670 Elite AX WiFi/BT (RZ616) is not available on 22.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1475667/x670-elite-ax-wifi-bt-rz616-is-not-available-on-22-04) but somewhat different. The wifi hardware of my laptop happens to be the same to that thread (RZ616). What makes different is that instead of wifi connection not working, my laptop just crashes and reboot (either starting NetworkManager service or run `dhclient`).</del>

After running `dhclient`, I found that problem is more likely to be RTL8111/8168/8411 PCIe (stuck and reboot when `dhclient enp7s0`, where `enp7s0` could be inferred by `lshw -c network` or `lspci`). Though tried out some solutions in [Ubuntu 20.04 Ethernet R8168](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1327697/ubuntu-20-04-ethernet-r8168), roll back driver to `r8168-dkms` may still failed to boot if laptop power not completely removed.

**Solution 1: Completely remove power.**

> Okay, this seems a bit absurd, but the solution here was to shutdown, disconnect my computer from power for a few minutes, reconnect the power cable, then reboot.

So in this case, before booting into LiveCD or into Ubuntu OS, make sure power has been completely removed. Since laptop (battery + cable) is not the same to computer (cable only), one may perform:

- A hard shutdown or reboot (pressing power button 8-15 sec)
- For this laptop, entering BIOS to disable built-in battery (perhaps a better way imposing less damage to motherboard)

**Solution 2: Disable ethernet driver RTL8111/8168/8411.**

For dual-boot laptop, if one does not need ethernet connection, then disable the RTL8111/8168/8411 driver in **either** Windows or Linux could resolve this problem.

- In Windows, disable `Realtek PCIe GbE Family Controller`;
- In Linux, disable driver by `rmmod r8168` or `rmmod r8169`, depending on the driver installed.

By this way, both Windows and Linux systems are able to be booted, without the need to remove power.

Comment: You may want to file a [bug report](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug). This bug may be related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2020617). If you think so, mark yourself as affected by the already reported bug. Don't forget to accept your answer as correct by clicking on the gray check mark next to it and turn it green ✅.

Comment: @user68186 I then found it's probably not a problem of wifi hardware, but more probably  ethernet hardware, so probably not related. And thanks for this suggestion! (though I'm really not familiar on linux and computer itself) I'll try to check if it's a bug and then report.

Comment: Thanks for the update, I think it will be useful for several other users of the same or similar hardware.